# nginx rewrite base url

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I would like the root url

```
http://www.example.com
```

to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/something/else
```

This is because some weird WP plugin always sets a cookie on the base url, which doesn't let me cache it.

I tried this directive:

```
location / {
    rewrite  ^  /something/else  break;
}
```

But 1) there is no redirect and 2) pages start shooting more than 1,000 requests to my server. With this one:

```
 location / {
        rewrite  ^  http://www.example.com/something/else  break;
    }
```

Chrome reports a redirect loop.

What's the correct regexp to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really want to be matching *exactly* the root URL in your location block, not "absolutely everything":

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /something/else break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
location / {
   rewrite  ^/$  /something/else  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`rewrite` statement](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) performs an internal rewrite by default unless the target is an absolute URL or you set the `redirect` or `permanent` flags. Something like this would return an HTTP redirect to the client:

```
rewrite ^/$ /something/else redirect;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this :

```
location = / {
     rewrite ^/$    http://example.com/an/other/path;
}
```

Nginx sends a HTTP 302 redirect to the client automatically when the rewriten URL starts with the 'http' scheme.